# Abort a test in a DejaGNU testsuite

Tags: testing, tcl

I'm writing a regression testsuite for Freeciv and need to set up a few things each time before running each actual test. In this boilerplate test code, things could conceivably go wrong, like failing to connect to the server for example. If this happens, I want to abort the rest of that test, since it's pretty much guaranteed to cause the rest of the tests to fail slowly and horribly.

How can I abort a test run without causing runtest itself to bail out? I want it to still output summary information, and I don't want to wrap everything in a conditional, because that's ugly. Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Is dejagnu built on top of tcltest? I know how to do such things with tcltest (which is used to test Tcl itself) but I don't know if my knowledge is useful to your problem…

Comment: @DonalFellows it's built on top of expect(1). I don't think it has anything to do with tcltest, other than having tcl as a common base layer.